# lag a zoo object by different time periods

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo object where the time component is hourly ie...

```
2009-04-01 00:00:00
2009-04-01 01:00:00
...
2013-03-20 23:00:00
```

I know that I can use `lag(zoo, k=-1)` to get the previous hour.  How can I get the same hour from the previous day?  It isn't as simple as setting `k=-24` because my data is in prevailing time so it skips an hour when the time changes forward.  (I dropped the 25th hour on the days when the time changed backwards so there's never more than 24 hours in a day).

Do I need to manually account for the time change in some way to force a solution based on the above?  My assumption is that there is a better way.

Comment: Rather than use the described ad hoc adjustment use GMT time zone or use chron class in which case you won't have time zone problems in the first place.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I'm looking through the chron package documentation on cran but I don't see anything immediately apparent in it that would solve my problem.  Converting it to GMT time might work I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: The point is that chron does not use time zones so the problems you are having won't arise in the first place.  Read the R Help Desk article in R News 4/1 : http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf